# Occlusion culling 3D transformed 2D rectangles?

Tags: c, graphics, 3d, geometry

So, to start off, *I'm not very good at computer graphics*. I'm trying to implement a GUI toolkit where one of the features is being able to apply 3D transformations to 2D "layers". (a layer only has one Z coordinate, as pre-transform, it's a two dimensional axis aligned rectangle)

Now, this is pretty straightforward, until you come to 3D transformations that would push the layer back, requiring splitting the layer into several polygons in order to render it correctly, as illustrated here. And because we can have transparency, layers may not get completely occluded, while still requiring getting split.

So here is an illustration depicting the issue and the desired outcome. In this scenario, the blue layer (call it **B**) is on top of the red layer (**R**), while having the same Z position (but **B** was added after **R**). In this scenario, if we rotate **B**, its top two points will get a Z index lower than 0 while the bottom points will get an index higher than 0 (with the anchor point being the only point/line left as 0).

[image: example]

Can somebody suggest a good way of doing this on the CPU? I've struggled to find a suitable algorithm implementation (in C++ or C) that would be appropriate to this scenario.

***Edit:*** To clarify myself, at this stage in the pipeline, there is no rendering yet. We just need to produce a set of polygons for each layer that would then represent the layer's transformed and occluded geometry. Then, if required, rendering (either software or hardware) is done if required, which is not always the case (for example, when doing hit testing).

***Edit 2:*** I looked at binary space partitioning as an option of achieving this but I have only been able to find one implementation (in `GL2PS`), which I'm not sure how to use. I do have a vague understanding of how BSPs work, but I'm not sure how they can be used for occlusion culling.

***Edit 3:*** I'm not trying to do colour and transparency blending at this stage. Just pure geometry. Transparency can be handled by the renderer, and overdraw is okay. In this case, the blue polygon can just be drawn under the red one, but with more complicated cases, depth sorting or even splitting up the polygons may be required (example of a scary case like that below). Although the viewport is fixed, because all layers can be transformed in 3D, creating a shape shown below is possible.

So what I'm really looking for is an algorithm that would **geometrically** split layer **B** into two blue shapes, one of which would be drawn "above" and one of which would be drawn below **R**. The part "below" would get overdraw, yes, but it's not a major issue. So **B** just need to be split into two polygons so it would appear to cut through **R** when those polygons are drawn in order. No need to worry about blending.

[image: circular]

***Edit 4:*** For the purpose of this, we cannot render anything at all. This all has to be done purely geometrically (producing **2D** polygons). This is what I was originally getting at.

***Edit 5:*** I should note that the overall number of quads per subscene is around 30 (average). Definitely won't go above 100. Unless the layers are 3D transformed (which is where this problem arises), they are just radix sorted by Z positions before being drawn. Layers with the same Z position are drawn in order in which they were added (first in, first out).

*Sorry if I didn't make it clear in the original question.*

Comment: Depending on how general the solution needs to be, there's an overview of the issues [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting) (from an OpenGL POV).

Comment: +1 just for the presentation of this. Though one could argue it is a what-have-you-tried issue with reasonable wood behind the arrow, it is clear some thought has gone into the issue. I don't program GL-graphics to save my life, and I'm genuinely intrigued by the question.

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to accomplish by not using a GPU to do this?  OpenGL or other flavors of API will make this so mech easier and portable.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: This is meant to work on several platforms, some of which don't have any OpenGL capabilities and are only capable of filling out 2D textured polygons (and some don't even have GPUs, so this would have to be done in pure software). The idea is to have a universal way of building the scene graph and then just have the backend draw the polygons.

Comment: This will force you into least common denominator style coding.  Running an XBox360 at Color Gameboy style graphics won't be very popular.  This is probably a case where you would want to do an OpenGL solution and a "fake" solution for the lower end systems.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: The systems have the same "tier" of output devices, just a variety of graphics acceleration hardware. The renderer should just draw textured polygons (with alpha channels). That's it. It **absolutely** must not do anything apart from drawing polygons. No stencil buffers or any other stuff like that.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: In fact, OpenGL is not available on most of them. The GPU is literally there to draw and blit textured polygons.

Comment: Sounds a lot like the handheld/embedded style stuff I've had to work with.  And you are of course correct, you cannot do any sort of rendering work outside of the renderer or "bad" things happen.  I've been spoiled lately and haven't had to think about poly subdivision.  It has been magically handled for me via hardware for a long time - or avoided on systems that couldn't effectively handle it without glitching the the Nintendo DS.  Setting up a good Oct-tree/BSP and using it to cull and possibly divide geometry is where I might start.  'Doom' level complexity is where you need to be.

Comment: Oh no. What's odd is the occlusion culling code in QuartzCore is only like 1500 lines, which does this sort of splitting. I think it uses binary surface partitioning to do the splitting. And yes, you're right, I am targeting embedded devices.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30149/discussion-between-christina-brooks-and-michael-dorgan)

Comment: Quartz core - Apple land?  You should add an apple/ios tag if so for more eyes.  If you are just using that as an example then nevermind.  I've done some BSP work a few years back - let me see if I can dig up a couple of good web links for you...

Comment: Well, I was planning on making something similar to QuartzCore, but erm, I don't think this question is in any way related to it. It's just about geometry and achieving a certain task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you "aren't good with computer graphics", Doing it on CPU (software rendering) will be extremely difficult for you, if polygons can be transparent.

The easiest way to do it is to use GPU rendering (OpenGL/Direct3D) with [Depth Peeling technique](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs5610/lectures/OrderIndependentTransparency.pdf).

*Cpu solutions*:

**Soltuion #1 (extremely difficult)**:

(I forgot the name of this algorithm).

You need to split polygon B into two, - for example, using polygon A as clip plane, then render result using painter's algorithm.
To do that you'll need to change your rendering routines so they'll no longer use quads, but textured polygons, plus you'll have to write/debug clipping routines that'll split triangles present in scene in such way that they'll no longer break paitner's algorithm.

Big Problem: If you have many polygons, this solution can potentially split scene into infinite number of triangles. Also, writing texture rendering code yourself isn't much fun, so it is advised to use OpenGL/Direct3D.

This can be extremely difficult to get right. I think this method was discussed in "Computer Graphics Using OpenGL 2nd edition" by "Francis S. Hill" - somewhere in one of their excercises.

Also check wikipedia article on [Hidden Surface Removal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_surface_determination).

**Solution #2 (simpler)**:

You need to implement multi-layered [z-buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering) that stores up to N transparent pixels and their depth.

**Solution #3 (computationally expensive)**:
Just use [ray-tracing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_%28graphics%29). You'll get perfect rendering result (no limitations of depth peeling and cpu solution #2), but it'll be computationally expensive, so you'll need to optimize rendering routines a lot.

**Bottom line:**

If you're performing software rendering, use Solution #2 or #3. If you're rendering on hardware, use technique similar to depth-peeling, or implement raytracing on hardware.

**--edit-1--**

required knowledge for implementing #1 and #2 is ["line-plane intersection"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-plane_intersection). If you understand how to split line (in 3d space) into two using a plane, you can implement raytracing or clipping easily.

Required knowledge for #2 is "textured 3d triangle rendering" (algorithm). It is a fairly complex topic.

In order to implement GPU solution, you need to be able to find few OpenGL tutorials that deal with shaders.

**--edit-2--**

Transparency is relevant, because in order to get transparency right, you need to draw polygons from back to front (from farthest to closest) using painter's algorithms. Sorting polygons properly is [impossible in certain situation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Painters_problem.svg), so they must be split, or you should use one of the listed techniques, otherwise in certain situations there will be artifacts/incorrectly rendered images.

If there's **no** transparency, you can implement standard zbuffer or draw using hardware OpenGL, which is a very trivial task.

**--edit-3--**

> I should note that the overall number of quads per subscene is around 30 (average). Definitely won't go above 100.

If you will split polygons, it can easily go way above 100.

It might be possible to position polygons in such way that each polygon will split all others polygon.

Now, 2^29 is 536870912, however, it is not possible to split one surface with a plane in such way that during each split number of polygons would double. If one polygon is split 29 timse, you'll get 30 polygons in the best-case scenario, and probably several thousands in the worst case if splitting planes aren't parallel.

Here's rough **algorithm outline** that should work:

1. Prepare list of all triangles in scene.
2. Remove back-facing triangles.
3. Find all triangles that intersect each other in 3d space, and split them using line of intersection.[image: line of intersection]
4. compute screen-space coordinates for all vertices of all triangles.
5. Sort by depth for painter's algorithm.
6. Prepare extra list for new primitives.
7. Find triangles that overlap in 2D (post projection) screen space.
8. For all overlapping triangles check their rendering order. Basically a triangle that is going to be rendered "below" another triangles should have no part that is above another triangle.
   8.1. To do that, use camera origin point and triangle edges to split original triangles into several sub-regions, then check if regions conform to established sort order (prepared for painter's algorithm). Regions are created by splitting existing pair of triangles using 6 clip planes created by camera origin points and triangle edges. [image]
   8.2. If all regions conform to rendering order, leave triangles be. If they don't, remove triangles from list, and add them to the "new primitives" list.
9. IF there are any primitives in new primitives list, merge the list with triangle list, and go to #5.

By looking at that algorithm, you can easily understand why everybody uses Z-buffer nowadays.

Come to think about it, that's a good training exercise for universities that specialize in CG. The kind of exercise that might make your students hate you.

Comment: Hm, solution #1 sounds like the only appropriate solution considering the fact that I need to do culling completely separately of rendering.  (If I understand correctly, Z-buffering is done at rendering stages)

Comment: @ChristinaBrooks: That's the most difficult solution. It'll be easier to handle transparency at rendering stage using #2 (software render only), #3 or using Depth Peeling. Of course, unless somebody already wrote a library that can be used for solution #1 (perhaps [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) has something useful?). Anyway, it is up to you to decide which one you want to implement.

Comment: I don't see how transparency is relevant, unless I was optimizing for eliminating overdraw. I'm not trying to split the blue polygon into a blue and a red-blue blended polygon, just into two blue polygons and then draw the first one under and the second one above the red one (in this case, the whole blue polygon can just be drawn below the red one, but with more complex transforms (ie. circular overlap) splitting may be required).

Comment: @ChristinaBrooks: Transparency is relevant, because in order to get transparency right, you need to draw polygons from back to front (from farthest to closest) using painter's algorithms. Sorting polygons properly is [impossible in certain situation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Painters_problem.svg), so they must be split, or you should use one of the listed techniques, otherwise in certain situations there will be artifacts/incorrectly rendered images. If there's **no** transparency, you can implement standard zbuffer or draw using hardware OpenGL, which is a very trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to come out say give the simpler solution, which may not fit your problem.  Why not just change your artwork to prevent this problem from occuring.

In problem 1, just divide the polys in Maya or whatever beforehand.  For the 3 lines problem, again, divide your polys at the intersections to prevent fighting.  Pre-computed solutions will always run faster than on the fly ones - especially on limited hardware.  From profesional experience, I can say that it also does scale, well it scales ok.  It just requires some tweaking from the art side and technical reviews to make sure nothing is created "ilegally."  You may end up getting more polys doing it this way than rendering on the fly, but at least you won't have to do a ton of math on CPUs that may not be up to the task.

If you do not have control over the artwork pipeline, this won't work as writing some sort of a converter would take longer than getting a BSP sub-division routine up and running.  Still, KISS is often the best solution.

Comment: It's a dynamic scene created programmatically. The embedded CPUs in question are in fact not that bad for performing maths, and have SIMD extensions. So is BSP the best way to go? Keep in mind that we're talking about 30 or so odd polygons inside a layer at the very most. And occlusion culling is done per-layer-plane and only if needed (if 3D transforms are applied, which is not a common case).